# How to use MongooseJS's findOne() and get an array of results?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose and I can't figure out how to get the results of my database from mlab.

I know how to findOneAndUpdate, but I am having trouble getting the results. The Mongoose site, I feel is not as informative as it could have been in terms of explaining how to get a particular result.

My MongoDB database looks something like this. The name of the collection is TagstoFiles.

[image]

I want to use Mongoose to put return all file_id's for a given tag.

I could not understand how to use findOne and findById from [mongoose's site](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne).

I tried writing some code but to no avail.

```
router.post('/decrypt_download', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    var tags = req.body.ea;
    var arrayOfFiles = [];
    TagstoFiles.findOne({tag:tags[0]},function(err, file_id){
  var obj = JSON.parse(file_id);

});
//how to use ^
    res.send("Working.");
});
```

Can someone please explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is req.body.ea? Array, single value or something else?

Comment: @Mat.Now it is an array of tags

Comment: What document from mlab do you want to retrieve? Specified by id? By tag? or maybe you gest all elements from db?

Answer (score 0):

Here i explain how to use findOne and findById find usage its the same , to do what i understand you want you need to use find

```
var Wanted= require('../models/wanted');

Wanted.findOne({"idsearch":idofwantedele, "secondparam":otherfilter}).exec((err,result) =>{


 if (err) return res.status(500).send({message : "something for an error"});

 if (result ) {
     return res.status(200).send({message: "here the result has the object of type wanted"});
 }

 if (!result ){
  return res.status(400).send({message : "nothing with those filters"});
 }
});
```

findById

```
var Wanted= require('../models/wanted');

Wanted.findById(wantedid, (err, result) => {
 if(err) return res.status(500).send({message : "something for an error"});

 if(!result) return res.status(404).send({message : "nothing with those filters"});

 if(result) return res.status(200).send({message:"result is a wanted with wantedid"});

});
```

Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WantedSchema = Schema({
some: String,
secondparam:String,
reftootherschema: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Wanted',WantedSchema);
```